Como puedo concatenar dos clases
tengo un código super sencillo pero me pidieron dividirlo en clases distintas, es decir, una clase usuario y otra clase donde esta el menu con todas las opciones que le voy a mostar al usuario. y luego llamarlas a ambas para mostrarse en pantalla.
Esta es la primera parte del codigo:
public class Opciones {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese su usuario: ");
    String user = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su contraseña: ");
    String contraseña = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("¡BIENVENIDO!" + user);
    System.out.println("Elija un lugar para visitar:");

Luego viene la otra parte que son las opciones que debo tener en una clase:
Esta es la primera opción
//Opcion1
    System.out.println("1. Restaurantes:");
    //Submenu1
    System.out.println("1.1 - Henry´s");
    System.out.println("1.2 - El Totumazo de Mayeya. ");
    System.out.println("1.3 - Braza y Barril. ");
    System.out.println("1.4 - Restaurante Mar de las Antillanas. ");

Esta es la segunda opcion
//Opcion2
    System.out.println("2. Museos:");
    //Submenu2
    System.out.println("2.1 - Museo del Oro. ");
    System.out.println("2.2 - Museo de Arte Moderno. ");
    System.out.println("2.3 - Museo San Pedro Claver. ");
    System.out.println("2.4 - Museo Naval del Caribe. ");

Esta es la tercera opción
//Opcion3
    System.out.println("3. Discotecas");
    //Submenu3
    System.out.println("3.1 - El Bar Etico. ");
    System.out.println("3.2 - Jet-Set. ");
    System.out.println("3.3 - Engels. ");
    System.out.println("3.4 - Epico Social Club. ");

Esta es la opcion de confirmar
//Opcion4
    System.out.println("4. confirmar");

para la entrada de las opciones:
int opcion1 = sc.nextInt();
    int opcion2 = sc.nextInt();
    int opcion3 = sc.nextInt();
    var opcion4 = sc.nextInt();
  

Ahora vienen las sub-opciones
    //Menu y submenu
    switch (opcion1) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Henry´s. ");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("El Totumazo de Mayeya. ");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Braza y Barril. ");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Restaurante Mar de las Antillanas. ");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Operacion Invalida. ");
            break;
    }
    
    switch (opcion2) {
        case 1:
           System.out.println("Museo del Oro. ");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Museo de Arte Moderno. ");
            break;
        case 3:
           System.out.println("Museo San Pedro Claver. ");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Museo Naval del Caribe. ");
        default:
            System.out.println("opcion invalida. ");
            break;
    }
    
    switch (opcion3) {
        case 1:
           System.out.println("El Bar Etico. ");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Jet-Set. ");
            break;
        case 3:
           System.out.println("Engels. ");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Epico Social Club. ");
        default:
            System.out.println("opcion invalida. ");
            break;
    }
    switch (opcion4){
case 1:
    System.out.println("¡CONFIRMADO!");
    break;
    }
    
    sc.close();
}

static void Opciones1() {
    
}

